# Targeted Conditional Formatting in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel sheet with 15 columns of data. I want to check one of the columns, and highlight a cell if it is under 25,000,000. Just recording a macro I can do it and it gives me this code:

```
Sub ebitda_check() 
    'ebitda < 25MM Macro

    Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
    Formula1:="=25000000"

    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

But this doesn't account for the fact that the column I want to target may move around or be in a different column next time. How can I write something to check, for example, "if the column header is 'EBITDA', highlight anything under 25,000,000"?

Comment: Do you need a macro? Say your column A has the "EBITDA" column that you want to check for amounts under 25M.  In cell A2, you can enter this as the CF formula `=AND($A2<25000000,A$1="EBITDA")` and the applied to range could be `=$A$2:$O$1000`.  That should check the current row for under 25M, and the column header to see if it's `EBITDA`

Comment: @BruceWayne But the formula will only check for cells in Column A, shouldn't the formula be `=AND(A2<25000000,A$1="EBITDA")`

Comment: @BrownishMonster - Oh, good call. If it's checking for `EBITDA` as a header, then you can un-anchor the first part.

Comment: @BruceWayne do you mean replace the value in the cell with that code and not even use a macro? I'm not sure I understand. Or do you mean to include that logic somewhere in the macro. I feel like there must be some simpler code than what the recording gave me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub ebitda_check()

    Dim f As Range, sht As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    'find the header
    Set f = sht.Rows(1).Find("EBITDA", lookat:=xlWhole)

    'if found, format the content below the header
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = sht.Range(f.Offset(1, 0), sht.Cells(Rows.Count, f.Column).End(xlUp))
        With rng.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
                                          Formula1:="=25000000")
            .SetFirstPriority
            With .Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 255
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How would you find a column header that was longer and more complex using Find like in your response? Say the header was "Capacity to Repay Outstanding Total  Debt in 7 yrs (%)" Could you use a "LEFT" somehow?

Comment: You could use `lookat:=xlPart` if you wanted to search by part of the header.

Comment: Ok so you can give it any part of the header and xlPart will find it? no matter which part it is? so .Find("Capaci", lookat:=xlPart) will find it just the same as .Find("Capacity to Repay Outstanding Total", lookat:=xlPart)?